# Assigning occurrences of whitespace to variables

Tags: java

I was wondering if it possible to assign occurrences of characters to variable until I hit a white space character.
For instance if I have the string `"17 23 4 54 6 343 4"` How would I assign the first number 17 to a variable, and the next subsequent numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String values = "17 23 4 54 6 343 4";
String[] variables = values.split("\\s");
```

Now you've got an array `variables` that holds 17 in `variables[0]`, 23 in `variables[1]` and so on.

Comment: Note that those values will be of type `String`. To turn them into `ints` you would have to go through `Integer.parseInt` and add a try / catch around that.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "17 23 4 54 6 343 4";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

        while (s.hasNextInt())
            System.out.println(s.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
17
23
4
54
6
343
4
```

---

> How would I assign the first number 17 to a variable, and the next subsequent numbers.

If you literally want the first value in one variable, and the remaining string in another, you could do:

```
String input = "17 23 4 54 6 343 4";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

int firstValue = s.nextInt();
String remaining = s.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and a [list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just split on whitespace, then loop over the resulting array and convert the String representation of the numbers to actual ints.

Something like

```
String input = "17 23 4 54 6 343 4";
String [] inputTokens = input.split(" ");
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (String string : inputTokens) {
    result.add(new Integer(string.trim()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Scanner to class to read the String.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("17 23 4 54 6 343 4");
while(input.hasNextInt()) {
    int theValue = input.nextInt();
}
```